# Lowpass Butterworth filter design (own poles' calculations)

Tags: filter-design, butterworth

I'm trying to calculate coefficients for my Butterworth filter of my own. I've found [this article](https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ee538/AnalogFilterDesigns.pdf) that looks really reliable. But I'm trying to implement it in MATLAB and I'm getting bandstop filter.
Please find attached matlab script below:

```
clc, clear all, close all;
%DIGITAL BUTTERWORTH FILTER DESING  
%Butterworth LP with -3dB at fc and N order and G gain
fs = 10; %frequency sampling
fc = 1;   %cut off frequency
N = 2;      %filter order
G = 1;      %filter gain
wc = 2*pi*fc;

%analog filter design
%poles and zeros   
k = [1:1:N];
%poles searching
%sk = wc * exp(((j*pi)/(2*N))*(2.*k+N-1))
sk = wc * exp(j*(pi/2)) * exp(j*(2.*k+1)*pi/2*N);
z = 0;
G = 1;
[NUM,DEN] = zp2tf(z,sk,G);
%no zeros for LP
Hs = tf(1,DEN)

%filter analysis
figure(1);
subplot(3,1,1)
pzmap(Hs);
subplot(3,1,2)
impulseplot(Hs);
subplot(3,1,3)
stepplot(Hs);    
fvtool(1,DEN);
```

I've calculated poles according to equation $10.3.47$ in the article and created transfer function with this poles as a parameters. But `fvtool` shows bandstop filter instead of lowpass (as described in article). In `pzmap` I'm getting also pole on right side of $s$-plane so it seems to be unstable. I dont really know how to interpretet this results.

[image: impuleplot, stepplot and fvtool]

Maks

Comment: 10.3.47 equation ?

Comment: ahh sorry, I've havent attached link to mentioned article. I did edit

Comment: @Gilles are you able to help me?

Answer (score 1):

The poles of a butterworth filter are located in the s-plane at the locations:

$$s_{k} = \sigma_{k} + j \omega_{k}$$

Where:

$$\sigma_{k} = -sin(\theta_{k})$$ $$\omega_{k} = cos(\theta_{k})$$.

And:

$$ \theta_{k} = \frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2N} $$

Where $N$ is the filter order. So, simply create an array of these poles for your given order, and convert them to coefficients of the filter. (See Numerical Recipes in C for a routine for doing this).

When the coefficients are created, perform:

$$ a_{k} \leftarrow \frac{a_{k}}{\omega_{p}^{N-k}} $$

Where $\omega_{p}$ is the passband edge, that was prewarped into the analog domain. Then set the numerator $b_{0}$ to be $b_{0} = \frac{1}{a_{0}}$ for normalization and divide all $a_{k}$ by $a_{0}$, where the $\vec{a}$ are the coefficients of the denominator of course.

What you have now is an analog filter. To get a digital filter, transform the poles and zeros of the denominator and numerator polynomials respectively with the billinear transform.

I don't use MATLAB, so I cant help you with your code, but that is the basic description of the procedure to create a butterworth filter. I have it implemented in C and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved this problem myself. I've used equation from this article mentioned in first post. I've just implement it in matlab not enough precise.

```
clc, clear all, close all;

%ANALOG BUTTERWORTH FILTER DESING
%https://engineering.purdue.edu/~ee538/AnalogFilterDesigns.pdf
%Butterworth LP with -3dB at fc and N order and G gain

wc = 1000;   %cut off frequency
N = 2;      %filter order
G = 1;      %filter gain 

%analog filter design
%poles and zeros 

%poles searching
for k = 0:N-1
   sk(k+1) = wc*exp(j*(pi/2))*exp(j*(2*k+1)*(pi/(2*N)));
end

[NUM,DEN] = zp2tf([],sk,G);
b0 = DEN(end)*G      %gain normalization  

Hs = tf(b0,DEN)

figure();
freqs(b0,DEN)
figure();
plot(sk./10^2, 'x')
xlim([-10,10]);
title('Poles placement in s-plane')
```

Many thanks for your help,
Maks